# Get the alphachannel value from pixel under mouse cursor

Tags: delphi, gdi+

How can you get the alpha values from the pixel under the mouse cursor in TImage with GDIPlus with Delphi 2010?

I tried this but A is always 255?  What did I do incorrectly?

```
procedure TFormMain.Image1MouseMove ( Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
var
  GPBitmap: TGPBitmap;
  iColorRef: Cardinal;
  iColor: TColor;
  A, R, G, B: Byte;
  iARGB: ARGB;
begin

  if Assigned ( Image1.Picture ) then
    begin

      GPBitmap := TGPBitmap.Create ( Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle );
      try

      // Get alpha 0-255 from GPBitmap
      GPBitmap.GetPixel ( X, Y, iColorRef );
      iARGB := ColorRefToARGB ( iColorRef );
      A := GetAlpha ( iARGB );
      AlphaUnderCursor1.Caption := 'Alpha: ' + IntToStr ( A );

      iColor := Image1.Canvas.Pixels [ X, Y ];
      GetRGB ( iColor, R, G, B );
      Shape1.Brush.Color := iColor;

      finally
        GPBitmap.Free;
      end;

end;
```

Comment: Ok... did that but same result.
iStatus := GPBitmap.GetPixel ( X, Y, iColorRef );
iStatus = InvalidParameter?

Comment: Perhaps there's no transparency and the alpha is really 255?

Comment: No.. I drew 10 px line with alpha color which is visible, then moved mouse over the the drawn line....  the drawn line alpha color seems to be correct at least visually.

Comment: You might be able to draw transparently. But if the background was already opaque before you draw - it will remain opaque, regardless of the transparency of your line... .. I think...

Comment: @Sertac - Ok... I fill TImage with GPBitmap.GetHBITMAP ( aclBlack, iHBitmap );  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle := iHBitmap; The GetHBitmap which is needed to assign a GPbitmap to TImage.  I have read that HBitmap does not pass alpha.  Is there another way to fill Image1.Picture.Bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the images on the monitor have no transparency.

At a fundamental level every *pixel* you see on the monitor has no transparency.

i.e. imagine hitting <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd>, and pasting a copy of your desktop into Paint.  You won't find any partially transparent pixels because there are none. At the very least you will see the pixels of your wallpaper.

Sorry for the inconveince.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The secret is to create a back buffer png image with
the same image and read the alpha channel from that with the screen image's 
mouse move event. The following code shows how to achieve this.

```
type
  TForm16 = class(TForm)
    Image1 : TImage; //Load SomeFile.png
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;  
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    PNGImage1 : TPNGImage; //Load SomeFile.png into this as well
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form16: TForm16;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm16.FormCreate( Sender : TObject );
  begin
    PNGImage1 := TPNGImage.Create();
    PNGImage1.Assign( Image1.Picture ); //Assign SomeFile.png
  end;

procedure TForm16.FormDestroy( Sender : TObject );
  begin
    PNGImage1.Free();
  end;

procedure TForm16.Image1MouseMove( Sender : TObject; Shift : ShiftState; X, Y : Integer );
  var
    Alpha: PByte;
  begin
    Alpha := @PNGImage1.AlphaScanline[Y]^[X];

      if( Alpha^ > 0 ) then
          Image1.Cursor := crDrag
        else
          Image1.Cursor := crDefault;

    Statusbar1.Panels[0].Text := IntToStr( Alpha^ );
  end;

end.
```

Use this image or any other image with Alpha transparency.

[image: An image to use]